# Is it rude to ask questions ending with 'or not'?

Tags: questions, politeness

I'm not a native speaking English person. 
I asked questions like this "You want a drink of water, or not?"
"You want to have a pizza, or not?'

Then I was criticized by a native English speaker who claimed these questions are rude. Are they?
And I was supposed to start them with "Do you...?".  Do I have to use "Do you" every time I ask a question?

Best regards, 
P.

Comment: They are sometimes rude, but sometimes not.  There is no answer to the general question you ask.

Comment: It's not necessary to add *or not*. It's quite sufficient just to ask: *Would you like a drink of water?* or *Would you like a pizza?*

Comment: It could be said in a rude manner (i.e., emphatically), but it isn't rude simply as a question.  However, it isn't necessary and has a nuance.  If you ask "Do you want to eat a pizza?", there are a lot of possible answers, including, "I think I'd rather have a sandwich."  If you end the question with "or not", you're implying a binary choice.

Comment: Good question without an easy answer. The way the question is asked - the intonation, the rhythm, the emphases ... (the prosody) is definitive and can be highly nuanced.

Comment: Yes, adding the gratuitous *or not* tends to make the questions sound rude. If there is a significant pause before *or not*, the question might possibly sound contemplative instead of rude.

Comment: "Or not" is almost always unnecessary, and can make give a clear, short answer to the question more difficult.

Comment: The other choice may be towards a passive person who always says yes. The or not may be an invitation that saying 'nah' or 'no' is perfectly fine.

Comment: Just adding that the "proper" way to ask such a question _politely_ is "Would you [...]". For some people, even "Do you [...]" might come off as too direct (especially if you're in a formal context) and therefore rude.

Comment: The "or not" is often used for emphasis when a question is asked a second time because the person didn't answer or was ambiguous the first time. "Do you want pizza"? -- "I like Round Table" -- "Yes, but do you want pizza or not?"  Using this form is kind of chastising the person for his bad first answer, which might well be considered rude.

Answer (score 45):

The "...or not?" phrasing seems to imply that your correspondent has been undecided for a while, changing decisions back and forth and you are now urging them to make up their mind once and for all.

> -- Let's go for a walk.
>
> -- OK. But give me 5 minutes.
>
> -- OK.
>
> // 5 minutes later
>
> -- Hey? Are you coming?
>
> -- Umm... I don't know. I still need some time.
>
> -- How much time do you need?
>
> -- Another 5 minutes.
>
> -- OK...
>
> // Another 5 minutes later
>
> -- So are you coming **or not**?

So I would say that **or not** may imply some sort of urgency or finality that may come across as rude in some situations, but naturally much depends on the context.

Comment: I think this is the nub of it, it is a phrasing that for native speakers is often reserved for an 'argumentative' situation and will therefore tend to make people feel defensive when it is used outside of that context.

Comment: Yes i agree, good answer. You might as well say... "hurry up". That is certainly rude.

Comment: In other contexts, it can add politeness, though. If I say to my boss "This book seems to be misfiled. Would you like me to refile it, or not?" it can mean "...or am I actually wrong and it is filed correctly?" i.e. it's less presumptuous.

Comment: @MissMonicaE that also changes the subject of the question though. If you're asking "should *I* do X or not?" (first person) it *can* be interpreted in a "rude" manner but is very dependent on tone and context; if it's a situation where the listener knows you genuinely do not know whether you should, no rudeness would be interpreted. If you're asking "are *you* going to do X or not?" (second person) though, it frequently -- but not always -- implies some sense of urgency and/or impatience.

Comment: This answer is correct. I think I would describe the typical use as *exasperation* or annoyance at the other person's waffling or delays. "I've been waiting 30 minutes, are you coming *or not*?"

Answer (score 6):

Tone of voice counts for a lot.

If I heard a non-native English speaker asking whether I wanted water, *or not*? with a pleasantly rising-pitched, questioning inflection at the end, I'd think differently about the asker's mood, intentions and attitude than I would if I heard anybody, native or otherwise, talking about whether I wanted water *or not* in a blunt, downward-pitched rhetorical-statement sounding inflection at the end.

Comment: Sure, we allow non-native speakers a fairly wide latitude, but if a native speaker added "...or not", even with an upward inflection, I'd probably interpret it as *thinly disguised exasperation* in most contexts, or perhaps view it as *passive aggressive*.

Answer (score 2):

The standard way to ask a question in English is Do you [verb].

Do you want to have a pizza? Or not?
Do you want to have a pizza, or not?

If you chose to not use Do you as the regular form of question, this usually implies either that you know the person well and maybe that you have been having a longer conversation up to the point when the question is asked.

Want to have a pizza, or not?
Want to have a pizza or not?

Dropping off the Do you is informal but most of all  implies you are already in a conversation or hanging around with a person when you ask the question. So, it can be seen as rude if you ask a question without it.

Often, with children who have been making a ruckus, a parent might leave off the Do you in asking the question. In that sense, it is almost a threat meaning: If you [the child] do not start behaving well, you can't have a pizza. So, it can also denote annoyance or irritation. Couples when annoyed with each other might also leave off the Do you. Also, good friends might leave it off because they know each other well and in that case, it is merely informal.

The or not is neither rude nor not rude.

Answer (score 1):

The more your question emphasizes the "or not" phrase, the more impatience a native English speaker will generally perceive in the way the question was asked. I.e. "Do you want a pizza or not?" is generally fine (although the "or not" is superfluous) "Do you want a pizza OR NOT?" would generally imply "Make up your mind!"

Also, "Do you ...." is generally used, as opposed to "Do". A better colloquial usage might be to just shorten the question to a single noun: "Pizza?" which could be used in place of "Do you want to share my pizza?", "Do you want to go out for pizza?", etc.